# adding inline tags for multiple entity types

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking to build a feature that behaves as follows (working in Angular):

- A textfield where the user can type.
- If the user types '@employee', a typeahead appears with a list of employees to select from.  When the user selects an employee, I show the employee name in a different color, or a different border, that is clickable
- If the user types '@office', a typeahead appears with a list of offices
- etc for different entity types

I get the sense that this isn't the typical behaviour of using '@'.  For example, with Trello, when you type @, and then a character, a popup appears with people's names.  i.e., the '@' assumes it's a person, rather than any entity

Three questions:

1) Is there a more accepted convention of allowing people to insert an entity (either a person, a place, or a whatever) in text?

2) Are there any libraries that can accomplish this behaviour?

3) If the answer to 2 is no, then the way I'm thinking of building this is to constantly watch what the user types, and if the user types one of the accepted tokens (@employee, @office, etc), then show the typeahead popup.  This seems straight forward to do, but for some reason, feels odd...not sure why.

Any thoughts or guidance?

Comment: is the text field and input or a textarea?

Comment: was thinking textfield.  would textarea be different?

Comment: For 1, usually you have a single field which which will be an autocomplete/typeahead without having to type any special characters. If you want it activate on a special character, then you are forced to build it out as you mentioned in point 3. For 2, you can probably angular-ui bootstrap's typeahead or almighty-autocomplete.

Comment: In any sense, you are describing pretty customized behavior, so I think you'll have to do a mix of 2 and 3.

Comment: Well, in HTML there is no <textfield> tag, you have <input type='text' /> or you have <textarea>, hence my question